# How does Applescript `string id` work?

Tags: applescript

The [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCIAHJF) states that `string id {104, 101, 108, 108, 111}` is "hello". However when I use:

```
log (string id {104, 101, 108, 108, 111})
```

then the printout is «(*string 104, 101, 108, 108, 111*)» and not "hello". Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some experimenting I found out I have to use:

```
log (string id {104, 101, 108, 108, 111} of me)
```

otherwise the `tell application "iTunes"` and messes everything up.

Comment: Yes, the log command is an applescript command not an iTunes command. So if you use it inside of an application tell block of code then you must preface it with "my" or end with "of me" to let applescript know that the command is supposed to be executed by applescript and not the application. That goes for any standard applescript command that you place inside any application tell block of code.

Comment: Of course the `log` was just for debug purpose to find out what was going on. Thanks for the insight so I know why it is this way.